# MongoDb not saving Java POJO part of a spring application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the following Java Pojo part of an application I am making:

```
@Document
public class Resume implements ResumePlan,Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5332235643191283709L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Objective objective;
    @Autowired
    private PersonalDetails personalDetails;
    @Autowired
    private Skills skills;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Experience experience;
    @Autowired
    private Education education;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private References references;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Publications publications;
}
```

I am saving it by the following code:

```
mongoOperations.insert(resume);
```

When I check on the backend in the mongodb console:
following is getting stored:

> db.resume.find();
>   { "_id" : "test@abc.com+919876543210", "_class" : "com.springmyresume.resume.Resume" }

It is not storing the rest of the bean objects like PersonalDetails etc..

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

*It is solved. I made the following changes.
1) Removed @Autowired annotation
2) Added @DBRef annotation
With the @Autowired annotation the field objects were not getting saved.
I don't know why this is the behaviour.*

Comment: I don't know how mondoDB works but I assume you should be telling it which fields to persist.

Answer (score 1):

First please make sure that you have all necessary fields' classes (`Objective`, `PersonalDetails`) annotated as `@Document`.

For second, please provide getters and setters for fields objects.

Also please make sure, that you have specified actual `@Id`, otherwise spring will do it for you.

BTW, if you would like to not use embedding, you may use `@DBRef` annotation. Here is quite good information:

http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/30/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects/

Comment: I have annotated the field classes with document and have added specified the ID as well. Will try the DBRef annotation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please do not forget about getters/setters. Otherwise Spring-Data-Mongodb won't be able to read field's values.

Comment: I set the getters and setters as well but it is of no help.